# Azure DevLabs include VM in the private network

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

Our organization is considering the deployment of testing VM's for Azure DevLabs.
To work with the internal API, we need to include the virtual machine in the private network of our organization (with Active Directory). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What documentation have you consulted already?

Comment: @kmoser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect But I'm not sure that AAD Connect will allow us to access from the VM to a private network like a VPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually , we can integrate on-premises AD with Azure by [Installing a replica Active Directory domain controller in an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-install-replica-active-directory-domain-controller#scenario-diagram).

If you want to join your VM to your On-premise AD or Integrate your on-premises directories with the DC VMs in your Devlab,  You need to create a Site-to-Site VPN between your VNet in your Devlab and On-premise. The main steps for using VNet in Devlab are below:

1. Go to Azure portal > Select your Devlab > Configuration and policies > Virtual Networks > Add > Select a VNet in your Devlab resource group> Enable the required options > Save
2. Create a Devlab VM with the VNet you have created (You can use private IP for it).
3. [Create a a Site-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) between your VNet in your Devlab and On-premise.
4. Configure DNS Server for the VNet. You can use the IP of your On-premise DC for it.

[image]

Then the VMs in Devlab are integrated with your on-premise private network. You can try to download RDP file from portal and try to RDP it from its private IP address to test it.

VMs in Devlab is different from others, I didn't test this, but it should work. Because the VMs just use VNet, and the Vnet can connect your private Network.

You can also refer to [this blog](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/extend-active-directory-to-microsoft-azure) to find more details about Extending Active Directory to Microsoft Azure.